# Can double lose its precision when converting from decimal in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion, double, decimal

For example, I have something like this code:

```
double a = 68.24;
double b = 0.01;
double c = a - b;
```

`c` is equal to `68.22999999999999`. And let's say that I cannot change types of `a`, `b` and `c` (it **should** be `double`). But I can do this:

```
double a = 68.24;
double b = 0.01;
decimal _c = (decimal) a - (decimal) b; 
double c = (double)_c;
```

Now `c` is `68.23`, which is what I need.

But could I lose precision of `c` converting from `decimal` `_c` if I have different values of `a` and `b`?

More broadly, when `double` lose its precision? Because, `a` and `b` in debugger are precise (or at least it is what it shows), if I convert them to `decimal` they are precise too. But operation on them somehow creates imprecise value.

Answer (score 0):

You know how if you try to write out 1/3 using a decimal point, it's impossible do precisely? The same is true of many binary values. When working with floating point values in code, you almost always only have an **approximation** of the exact value you think you have.

The `decimal` type helps because is uses the twice the bits to represent a *significantly smaller* possible range of values (±10<sup>28</sup> vs ±10<sup>300+</sup>). This gives us enough precision the rounding error *seems* to disappear for most things (it's still there, just too small to notice).

For the sample code in the question, the compiler is detecting we only have constants, and is optimizing away some of the conversions to and from `double`, so it seems we only work with `decimal` values until finally outputting the result.

> And let's say that I cannot change types of a, b and c (it **should** be double).

Regardless of that statement, if you care about the accuracy of the result, you probably need `decimal`.

So why would we ever use `double`? **Speed.** The `double` type is able to take advantage of mathematical instructions implemented and optimized directly in the CPU, making things sometimes 1000s of times faster vs implementing the math operations in software.